# Spring Boot not autowiring class in test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2 application with the following structure:

```
- src/main/java/com.mycompany/
---- application
---- domain
---- infrastructure
-------- persistence
------------ ...
-------- Application.java
- src/main/test/java/com.mycompany/
---- application
---- domain
---- infrastructure
-------- persistence
------------ testingutils
---------------- JdbcPersistenceHelper.java
------------ CurrenciesJdbcViewTest.java
```

Application class:

```
package com.mycompany.infrastructure;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

JdbcPersistenceHelper:

```
package com.mycompany.infrastructure.persistence.testingutils;

@Component
public class JdbcPersistenceHelper {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public JdbcPersistenceHelper(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
```

CurrenciesJdbcViewTest:

```
package com.mycompany.infrastructure.persistence;

@DataJpaTest
public class CurrenciesJdbcViewTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private JdbcPersistenceHelper persistenceHelper;

    private CurrenciesJdbcView view;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        view = new CurrenciesJdbcView(jdbcTemplate);
    }
```

However, when I run the test, I got an error on ApplicationContext loading as follows:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.mycompany.infrastructure.persistence.CurrenciesJdbcViewTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'persistenceHelper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.mycompany.infrastructure.persistence.testingutils.JdbcPersistenceHelper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

It seems that spring is not detecting and autowiring `JdbcPersistenceHelper` class even though it is placed in a subpackage of `com.mycompany.infrastructure` where my spring boot's application class is located, so I think it should be able to detect it without any further configuration. 
Am I missing something here?

Comment: How do you run the test class?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but in your JdbcPersistenceHelper @Autowired method, which is called when JPH is autowired, you take an EntityManager as an argument. Shouldn't that be autowired too or provided by whatever other way?

Comment: You're only using `@DataJpaTest` on your test class; most likely, your "helper" (which I recommend replacing with Spring Data JPA) isn't in that slice and needs to be added to it.

Comment: @chrylis I think you're right, I forgot that detail about `@DataJpaTest` only loading Spring Data repositories, so it's not going to "autoload" a regular `@Component` bean. Do you mind to post your answer so I can mark it as the right one? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only using `@DataJpaTest` on your test class; most likely, your "helper" (which I recommend replacing with Spring Data JPA) isn't in that slice and needs to be added to it using `includeFilters` or `@ContextConfiguration`.

Answer (score 3):

You have 'src/main/test/com.mycompany/' but that should be 'src/test/java/com/mycompany/'

I guess 'test' is seen as a package name and therefore not picked up by component scan.

If you want to use dependency injection for your tests, you might want to consider constructor injection in favor of field injection since it is considered better style and clearer (all required dependencies must be set).

I think I would not use D.I. at all for my tests but just instantiate any helpers as fields or in a @Before method. I don't really see a test as an application component but more as a standalone thing. Less complexity helps with understanding and maintaing tests in my experience.

Comment: yeah, you're totally right, but that's a typo on my question, not the cause of the issue. Thanks!!

Comment: @beni0888 the path in the question keeps being incorrect

Comment: @adriaan-koster I had already edited the question before you commented. I don't see where's the error you're claiming. I would be my pleasure to fix it if you help me to detect it.

Comment: You have 'src/main/test/com.mycompany/' but that should be 'src/test/java/com/mycompany/'